# Raspberry Pi is *sometimes* unreachable via the network

Tags: boot, ethernet, networking

I'm using my RPi as a flight controller in a Quadcopter project, when I'm at home the raspberry pi boots up fine and I'm able to connect my MacBook via Ethernet directly to the RPi and ssh in via its static IP, defined in cmdline.txt on the SD Card.

However, when I am in school and try the exact same setup (the only thing different is the socket I'm plugging the RPi into) it just doesn't work, my MacBook reports it as unreachable.

I'm a little confused as to why it doesn't work, as the setup is exactly the same.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the configuration of the network in both cases? It might be that the subnet/static IP you chose for the rPi does not conflict with network settings on your MacBook when you're at home, but does when you are at school.

Comment: Network configuration is exactly the same, 192.168.0.10 for the Mac, 192.168.0.70 for the RPi, the network is isolated and wifi is turned off, so not connected to any other networks.

Comment: Is the WiFi off on both devices? What do you mean by "(the only thing different is the socket I'm plugging the RPi into)" - the mains socket or something else?

Comment: I have the same problem at my school. I talked to IT, and the protocol that ssh uses has been disabled. They likely do that to stop torrenting and such at school.

Comment: Wifi is off on both devices yes, I mean the only thing different is the mains socket. No joke. Same mains to Micro USB cable too.